# Electric field due to a linear charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

Let's say I have a uniformly charged wire with some constant linear charge density. Along a line parallel to the $z$-axis and passing through $(0,y,0)$ and asked to find an electric field at a point $(p,q,r)$. Then the vector should be $p \textbf{i} +(q-y)\textbf{j}+r\textbf{k}$. My books say the field has no $z$ component and it takes vector as $p\textbf{i}+(q-y)\textbf{j}$. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Simplify the problem considering as infinite straight line with constant linear charge density $\:\lambda\:$ the $\:x-$axis. You have then rotational symmetry with respect to this axis. The method of solution depends on what are you studying : Coulomb Law or Gauss Law.

Comment: Related : [Why don't stationary charge feel force from a current carrying wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694928/why-dont-stationary-charge-feel-force-from-a-current-carrying-wire/694961#694961), Figure-03.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a question of symmetry. If the source (charge distribution) is z independent (the same for any z), then the field does not depend on z.
It can be mathematically proven, but a simple drawing is sufficient.
[image: Sum of two electric fields]

Consider two elementary segment of length $ dl_{1}$and$ dl_{2}$. They carry the charge $ dq= \lambda dl_{1}= \lambda dl_{2} $ This charges create at the M two electric fields:$ \overrightarrow{d E_{1} } $ and $ \overrightarrow{d E_{2} } $. The electric field intensity only depends on the charge and distance between source and point of observation. So $d E_{1}=d E_{2}=dE= \frac{dq}{4 \pi   \varepsilon _{0}  r^{2} }$
At the point of observation, the electric fields add up. The vertical components cancel out and one gets:
$ \overrightarrow{dE} =2.cos( \theta )dE  \overrightarrow{i}  $

Comment: hi, thanks for explanation. But I didn't get it. Can you explain about the drawing and if you can provide any link to the mathematical proof that will be very useful for me.

Comment: I have improved my answer, is it clearer?