# Will an induced magnetic field induce another electric field that will circulating around the induced magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Look at the picture that this question shows [The direction of induced electric field around a changing current wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/747570/the-direction-of-induced-electric-field-around-a-changing-current-wire)

[image]

Will the induced magnetic field (red circle) induce another electric field (blue circles) that circulating around the magnetic field like the picture below?

[image]

Comment: It is electromagnetic radiation that is generated by changing currents but not as the simple diagram you make. It needs mathematics to describe it. http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m6/production_of_em_waves.html

Comment: [Monopole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_antenna)