# Force on charge due to current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I know that a charge moving parallel to a straight current carrying conductor experiences a force towards that wire due to magnetic lorentz force. I am more curious about the idea where the charge is stationary and the wire is moved parallel to it in the opposite direction at the same speed. Will there be a force on the charge this time?

Comment: A moving wire has no net charge.

Comment: Related in not Duplicate : [Why don't stationary charge feel force from a current carrying wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694928/why-dont-stationary-charge-feel-force-from-a-current-carrying-wire/694961#694961).